# Split string into separate line according to container size

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gsap

I didn't find any proper solution inside old threads so...

I'm trying to replicate one of the feature of **SplitText** plugin of **GSAP** ([here is the reference](https://greensock.com/splittext/)).

I'm building a simple Gatsby website to learn a bit about react.
I've a simple component that will be rendered into several instances inside index.js.

Here is the simplified code for `feature.js`

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import classnames from 'classnames/bind'

import styles from '../styles/modules/feature.module.scss'

let cx = classnames.bind(styles)

const Feature = props => {
  const [state] = useState({
    id: props.id,
    subtitle: props.subtitle,
    title: props.title,
    description: props.description,
    content: props.contentPosition,
    image: props.imgPosition,
  })

  return (
    <section className={cx('feature')}>
      <div className={cx('featureContent', `${state.content}`)}>
        <div className={cx('featureContentInner')}>
          <div className={cx('subtitle')}>
            <h5>
              <span>{`${state.id}.`}</span>
              {state.subtitle}
            </h5>
          </div>
          <h1>
            <div className={cx('contentLine')}>
              <div className={cx('contentLineInner')}>Your peace of</div>
            </div>
            <div className={cx('contentLine')}>
              <div className={cx('contentLineInner')}>mind in the</div>
            </div>
            <div className={cx('contentLine')}>
              <div className={cx('contentLineInner')}>heart of Venice.</div>
            </div>
          </h1>
          <p>{state.description}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className={cx('featureImg', `${state.image}`)}>
        <div className={cx('featureImgInner')}>
          <img />
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  )
}

export default Feature
```

As you can see, I'm holding props inside my state and place them in my render methods.

The only thing that is **hard coded** is the `props.title` because I'm fetching a `String` and I need to split that String into several lines.
Since I've several instance with different `props.title` the length of each line should be calculated dynamically.

The structure could be replicated each time `h1 > div*x > div` but each time there could be a different `x`.

I'm asking to this board how would you tackle this or if there is a plugin or some script to make this simple instead of calculating tons of variables (`getBoundingClientRect` `split` `join` etc...).

Or maybe the only solution is to pay 99 bucks for a single shot on a plugin :P

Thanks!

Comment: "if there is a plugin or some script to make this simple instead of calculating tons of variables" - yep, that's be SplitText! It handles a lot of things that you haven't even considered yet, like complex characters and emojis.

Comment: @ZachSaucier solved with splitting.js. Next time GSAP Club, next time... 

Comment: Splitting.js is great for simple use cases. For more complex ones, it falls short though :)

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of forthcomers:

Setup a reference:

```
let paragraph = useRef(null);
```

This will be assigned to the text we would like to spilt:

```
<p ref={el => (paragraph = el)}>
  this is a simple paragraph that I'm trying to split
</p>
```

Next, we are going to setup an initial state based on how many max lines do you expect (don't worry if there will be less lines, like when resizing, they will be hidden):

```
const [content, setContent] = useState({
  firstLine: '',
  secondLine: '',
  thirdLine: ''
});
```

Then simply execute the splitting once the component did render.
With array function you can go as deep as you want: in my example I need the content of each line. I'll hide the generated splitting from Splittext.js and inject the result of each lines into my preformatted code.

```
useEffect(() => {
  // Split the paragraph into words and lines
  const splittedText = Splitting({ target: paragraph, by: 'lines' });

  // Get an Array of Lines that contains an array of Words
  const lines = splittedText[0].lines.map(line =>
    line.map(word => word.textContent)
  );

  // Get every single lines as an Array of Strings
  const contents = lines.map(line => line.join(' '));

  // Hide the original paragraph
  paragraph.style.display = 'none';

  // Change the content state
  setContent({
    firstLine: contents[0],
    secondLine: contents[1],
    thirdLine: contents[2]
  });
}, []);
```

Then just render how many lines of *how-nested-you-want* and with *how-many-classes-you-like* `divs`